# show-sql/format-sql properties not working @Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

`hibernate.format_sql` & `show_sql` properties not working at spring boot.

My properties like below.
I setup master & replica datasources.

```
  datasource:
    master:
      hikari:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
        username: ${username}
        password: ${password}
        maximum-pool-size: 5
        max-lifetime: 600000
    replica:
      hikari:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test
        username: ${username}
        password: ${password}
        maximum-pool-size: 5
        max-lifetime: 600000

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        show_sql: true
```

and configuration class below.

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.master.hikari")
    public DataSource imServiceCudDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.replica.hikari")
    public DataSource imServiceRoDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource(DataSource imServiceCudDataSource, DataSource imServiceRoDataSource) {
        return new TransactionRoutingDataSource(imServiceCudDataSource, imServiceRoDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource) {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(routingDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.example.demo");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateVendorAdaptor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateVendorAdaptor);
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager) {
        return new ReplicaAwareTransactionManager(jpaTransactionManager);
    }
}
```

When I test data insertion & selection It works fine but logging.
If I setup only master datasource It works.